# How to remove or hide horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, html

My container `div` adds a scroll bar below my `div` `#wrapper`.

[image: The problematic slider:]

This is my css for the `wrapper`

```
#wrapper {
   background:#383434;
   width:1000px;
   height:auto !important;
   min-height:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   height: 100%;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 5px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 5px#000;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 5px #01DF01;
   margin-top:20px;
   border-radius:5px;
   margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

How can I remove or hide the scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting/modifying `overflow:auto;` solves the problem. I think `hidden` is what you are looking for.

If you look [at the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) you can find what does the different values actually do:

> **visible**
>   Default value. Content is not clipped, it may be rendered outside the content box.
>
> **hidden**
>   The content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.
>
> **scroll**
>   The content is clipped and desktop browsers use scrollbars, whether or not any content is clipped. This avoids any problem with scrollbars appearing and disappearing in a dynamic environment. Printers may print overflowing content.
>
> **auto**
>   Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers like Firefox provide scrollbars if content overflows.

Comment: hehe sorry, i could have googled that=(.

so there is now *possible way it would show on ff or ie, if there wasnt an extension of some kind?

Comment: @user2725502 Why do you need any kind of extension if this works on all browser? I tested FireFox, Chrome, Opera and its fine on all.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: auto` means to show a scrollbar if the content overflows, which is happening in your case. Perhaps what you want is an `overflow: hidden`, which will not show any scroll bars. In your site, this seems to work.

The other option is to hunt down what it is that has a size overflowing your container and shrink it.

Comment: This makes height problems.

Comment: I had already checked every width, all falls under 1000px.

What does overflow hidden do?

Comment: Overflow hidden means to just not show anything that falls outside of the dimensions of the container. Although you have everything with a width <= 1000 px, things like box shadows may cause the children to take up more space than you expect.

Comment: Yea but shouldnt that appear on element check on google chrome?

Comment: ok, found it. It was `#middle` having a left and right margin that was causing the overflow. Changing those margins to 0 fixed the issue as well without changing the overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow-x: hidden` to the style for `#wrapper`.

**Edit:**

I'm finding that the margins for your `#middle` styling is causing that horizontal scrollbar to appear. Putting `margin-top: -55px` and clearing the `margin` property on it fixes the problem.

Comment: Can i ask what 'exactly' will that do?

Comment: This is a quick fix to make it so that horizontal overflow will not cause the horizontal scrollbar to appear. But the real issue might be that there is an element within the wrapper that is possibly extending it such that it needs a scrollbar.

Comment: i dont think the wrapper is being extended. already checked for that. was my first instinct.

Comment: Well, something is causing the wrapper to overflow, be it padding, margins, or anything that would add extra width inside of the wrapper.

Comment: Try the suggestion I just added as an edit to see if it works for you. Looks like the culprit here was `#middle`.